# Curl request from one VM instance to another VM (Vagrant) doesn't appear to work

Tags: php, curl, vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrantfile

I have two Virtual Machines running an instance of Scotchbox (Vagrant) and essentially there is the 'frontend' application (AngularJS) and the 'backend' application (Zend/PHP etc..)

I have them setup on two individual Vagrant instances and are running from the IP's below (added them to my Windows hosts file) so I may access them via the domain name (rather than just the IP address)

```
192.168.33.10 myappfront.local
192.168.33.11 myappback.local
```

In my frontend application I run the following PHP code with CURL to basically verify the token when a user logs in.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$parameters = $apiUrl . '/user/login/verify-new-ui?id='.$_REQUEST['id'].'&token='.$_REQUEST['token'].'&appid=3';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $parameters);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

$data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch)); // always NULL??
curl_close($ch);
```

The $parameters variable will contain a URL similar to this...
https://myappback.local/user/login/verify-new-ui?id=1000001445&token=1shg7x1y7u53c1cppg36&appid=3

When I try to var_dump out the $data variable it is always NULL - I know the function works (it is running on our live site fine) so leads me to believe this is something Vagrant related?

Is it something firewall related within the vagrant instance? Can anyone suggest the best way to figure this out?

My vagrantfile is as follows:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
config.vm.hostname = "scotchbox"
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
config.vm.box_download_insecure = false 

config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
end

config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap.sh"

end
```

// the other backend vagrant box

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11"
config.vm.hostname = "scotchbox"
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
```

end

Comment: Could you plase show, what stored in variable $apiUrl? And where did you add this:
192.168.33.10 myappfront.local
192.168.33.11 myappback.local
I mean on localhost or vagrant machine?

Comment: Should I need to edit the hosts file within the two vagrant instances?

Comment: Sure, if you add this records only on localhost - just you can test any request, use browser. If you need to make request from one VM to another, you should add the same config into VM which make request.

Comment: such a simple mistake.. but that fixed it... feel free too add your last comment as an answer and i will accept it and give you the +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add same records into VM, which make request. if you add this records only on localhost - just you can test any request, use browser.

Comment: if it helps others... use the following to amend the hosts file by using vagrant ssh then running this command.

sudo nano /etc/hosts